# MS Access VBA - Run Multiple Saved Imports on double click

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, import-from-excel

I'm trying to save myself some time as I update a few similar databases with new data every morning using saved imports. I currently have the following double-click code on a logo which checks to see if I'm the current user of the database (because I'm the only one who will be updating) and if I am the current user, run two saved imports:

```
Private Sub Image480_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sHostName As String

' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name
sHostName = Environ$("computername")


If sHostName = "GS100ZEC" Then
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Import-DocCreator CPD"
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Import-DocCreator CD"
End If

End Sub
```

The problem seems to be that it is only updating one of these tables with the new data, the second table stays the same. Any tips or something I may have missed would be appreciated!

**Update:**

Buddy of mine helped me formulate a loop for this function and still same problem, the second import is not running! Code as follows:

```
Private Sub Image480_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sHostName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim docs(1 To 2) As String

' Get Host Name / Get Computer Name
sHostName = Environ$("USERPROFILE")

docs(1) = "Import-DocCreator CPD"
docs(2) = "Import-DocCreator CD"

If sHostName = "C:\Users\z003nttv" Then
    For i = 1 To 2
    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport docs(i)
    Next i

End If
```

End Sub

Also tried to delete the saved import itself and recreating it, still didn't import.

Comment: Have you tried to manually run the 2nd import to see what results you get. Can you share what the import looks like?  Or if they are not 'order-dependent', run the 2nd one first in your code.

Comment: Actually Not Order Dependent, looks as if only the second import is working and it must be skipping the first. Asked my VBA buddy and he suggested I use a loop for something like this.

Comment: I still think you need to find out why the import doesn't 'do anything'. Also, not sure why a loop would solve anything. If it was a timing issue, then I would expect the first to run, then maybe skip the second.

Comment: Have you run the second import separately from this VBA to ensure that it works? Have you tried "stepping" through the code to see if the behavior is the same? You can do that by setting a [breakpoint](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/set_breakpoint2013.php) by clicking a line of code and pressing F9, running the code (by double-clicking your logo or pressing F5 when you have your cursor in the code) and then stepping through by pressing F8.

Comment: Please answer the question of running saved import separately outside code. If no errror is raised, my guess is a table validation issue where second import relies on data (i.e., related index) or import does not adhere to table structure (type, rules, etc.). Check source file for consistency.